# How to add ASCII symbol after each recent post

Tags: php, loop

How do I add an ASCII code after each recent post list item?

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a></li> ';}    
?>
```

So that the output would be

Recent post 1 > 
Recent post 2 >

EDIT1:

If i just put &agt; after `</a>`, the symbol it wil be part of the hyperlink. I just want it to be apart from the link.

```
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>&gt;</li> ';}    
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about (something like) this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 2,
);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent['ID']); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($recent["post_title"]); ?>">
            <?php echo $recent["post_title"]; ?>
        </a> &gt;
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

If so, what was the problem?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I'm new to php, so I'm still learning how to do these little things. But why do you use ID at the permalink, because now I see the post id as link and not the post title?

Comment: So now I see as output: 
213test > 
183test >

Instead of: Recent post title 1 >
Recent post title 2 >

Comment: Oke. I've just added &gt; after </a> but then it will be part of the hyperlink. I don't want that. Any other way?

Comment: If you put something **after** `<a>...</a>` it will **not** be part of it - unless the HTML is broken... Can I see this live somewhere? Or could you please update your code (into the question itself).

Comment: Please see post edit. Unfortunately I don't have a live preview because I'm working in local development.

Comment: Okay, you're not even using the code I presented - but nevermind. Yours should also do. Could you please include the HTML that your code generates? If you say, the `&gt;` is part of the link, then there's something wrong in the HTML.